# Have Rails app update two POSTGRES DB with the same information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, nitrousio, zapier

All,

I'm trying to set up a Rails app with two databases. I'd like the app to send identical data to both while in production.

The aim is to attach one DB to a Zapier account (www.zapier.com) so that data can be exported in a number of ways.

I'm using two (three if you count dev) Heroku Postgres accounts and I am deploying on Nitrous.io.

I've searched and tried a lot of options but can only find 2 X databases writing different info. (Which I still couldn't get running).

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use replication in Postgres i.e. have one master and replicate everything using the DB software?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend handling the replication at the database level. Postgres offers great master/slave replication that would work well for your use-case.  Here is a tutorial describing how to set it up:

[Tutorial](http://blog.codepath.com/2012/02/13/adventures-in-scaling-part-3-postgresql-streaming-replication/)